# HashMap.put isn't working as expected

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I'm trying to save a HashMap in another hashmap.

The problem comes when I save one key and value in the inner hashmap.

When I try to recover the value, always return null.

It's like HashMap doesnt work... Why??

I try to create a global variable protected and final.. and nothing :(

```
protected final Map<Integer,Map> HMG =  new HashMap<Integer,Map>(); //GLOBAL VARAIBLE

    List<org.jdom2.Element> hijos = root.getChildren();
    for(int i=0 ; i < hijos.size(); i++) {
        org.jdom2.Element elem = hijos.get(i);
        String file = elem.getName();
        HMG.put(i, new HashMap<String, String>());
        System.out.println("Hashmap saved to "+ i+" "+file );
        System.out.println(file + i);
        List<org.jdom2.Element> hijos2 =elem.getChildren();
        for (org.jdom2.Element e : hijos2){
            guardarAtributos(e,i);
        }
    }

public void guardarAtributos(org.jdom2.Element elemento,Integer orden) {
    List<org.jdom2.Attribute> atributos=elemento.getAttributes();
     Map<String,String> a =HMG.get(orden);
     for (org.jdom2.Attribute atrib : atributos) {
         a.put(atrib.getName(), atrib.getValue());
         System.out.println("Writting into miniHashMap ===> "+atrib.getName()+" "+" "+atrib.getValue());
         System.out.println("Testing:::::"+ a.get(0));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Hashmap saved to 0 Number
Number0
Writting into miniHashMap ===> value  3
Testing:::::null
Writting into miniHashMap ===> value  1
Testing:::::null
Writting into miniHashMap ===> value  4
Testing:::::null
Hashmap saved to 1 Number
Number1
Writting into miniHashMap ===> value  88
Testing:::::null
```

Edit!:
Thanks you, but when im triying to recover a value, using

```
public void recuperarHashMap(Integer orden){
 Map<String,String> hash= HMG.get(orden);
 for(Entry<String, String> entry: hash.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println(entry.getKey());
     System.out.println(entry.getValue());
 }
}
```

Test Class:

```
a.recuperarHashMap(0);
a.recuperarHashMap(1);
```

Output:

```
value
4
value
88
```

I only get the last value!! why?!!! Thanks you a lot :) im a noob! :(

Edit2 !!

The XML is like that (made with emf tool editor)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:language1="language1">
  <language1:Number id="PI">
    <has value="3"/>
    <has value="1"/>
    <has value="4"/>
  </language1:Number>
  <language1:Number id="888">
    <has value="88"/>
  </language1:Number>
</xmi:XMI>
```

Comment: if it doesn't put nothing, what does it put?

Answer (score 7):

You're not testing for the same thing you're putting in:

```
a.put(atrib.getName(), atrib.getValue());
...
System.out.println("Testing:::::"+ a.get(0));
```

`atrib.getName()` isn't the number 0, is it? If you change your code to:

```
System.out.println("Testing:::::"+ a.get(atrib.getName()));
```

you'll find it can recover the value with no problems. What did you expect `a.get(0)` to do? Were you perhaps expecting it to return the first element within the map? Maps don't work like that - the `get()` method fetches by *key*.

EDIT: If you're setting multiple entries with a key of `value`, that suggests you've got multiple attributes with a name of `value`. Note that you've got two loops:

```
for (org.jdom2.Element e : hijos2){
    guardarAtributos(e,i);
}
```

and:

```
for (org.jdom2.Attribute atrib : atributos) {
    a.put(atrib.getName(), atrib.getValue());
    ...
}
```

So if you've got multiple elements all with a `value` attribute then *yes*, the earlier values will be overwritten by the later ones.

I suspect you have XML like this:

```
<root>
  <child>
    <x value="3" />
    <y value="1" />
    <z value="4" />
  </child>
  <child>
    <x value="88" />
  </child>
</root>
```

... but you haven't shown us your XML, so we can't really say for certain.

EDIT: Now that we've seen your XML, it's not clear why you're using the attribute name at all, or why you want maps at all. It looks to me like you *really* want a `List<List<String>>`:

```
List<List<String> elementValues = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

List<Element> elements = root.getChildren();
for (Element element : elements) {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element child : element.getChildren()) {
        values.add(child.getAttributeValue("value"));
    }
}
```

This will be *much* simpler than using maps etc.

Comment: The key is always `value`. Your proposal is confusing. It will print the last value but the map will have only one entry.

Comment: @alexxino: Please edit that code into your question - and tell us what it's printing.

Comment: @jdb: No, the key is the name of the attribute.

Comment: Why does it print `value  3`, `value  1`, etc.? Doesn't that mean `atrib.getName()` is always `"value"`?

Comment: @jdb: How are we meant to know? We haven't the faintest idea what XML you're running against. Do you have any evidence that your XML is the same as alexxino's?

Comment: This code line `System.out.println("Writting into miniHashMap ===> "+atrib.getName()+" "+" "+atrib.getValue());` prints `Writting into miniHashMap ===> value  3` and only the number changes in the example. There may be different values in the rest of the XML but in the example they are all `"value"`. All I am saying is that your suggestion is confusing. And you can see that by the comment above.

Comment: ooohh crap! you are right!! ok ok thanks a lot! How can i do to save multiple keys with the same name without overwritting?

Comment: @jdb: If they're all `value` then that just shows that all the attribute names are `value`. As we don't know what the XML looks like or what the OP is actually trying to achieve, it's hard to know what to advise beyond explaining exactly why he's getting the behaviour he *is* getting.

Comment: @alexxino: It sounds like you might want a `Multimap` - I'd suggest using Guava for this: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com

Comment: @Jon Skeet Even if only two of the names were the same, your original suggestion was still confusing. We had 4 of them all the same in the example and none of them different. Why are we even arguing about that?

Comment: @jdb: I had misinterpreted your original comment, but fundamentally it was unclear what the OP was trying to achieve - and aside from anything else, my answer has always answered the question of why the OP couldn't get a value out. We've then moved on from there to the fact that what he was trying to do wasn't sensible with a map in the first place...

Comment: @jdb: See the end of my current edit. Now we've got a clearer picture of the context, it's easy to see a cleaner solution.

Answer (score -1):

The final varibale can't overwrite